# ASP.NET ListBox Always Returns First Value (-1 Selected Index)

Tags: .net, asp.net, listbox

I have two ASP.NET ListBoxex in a usercontrol.
databinding event fires once. i am sure and i did trace.
but listbox always returns first value !
it is strange for me.
and i don't know how to fix it.
thanks for help.
Here is Source of User Control :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPanel" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
<ContentTemplate>
    <table class="style1">
        <tr>
            <td align="left" dir="rtl" valign="top" width="250">
                <asp:ListBox ID="lst2" runat="server" DataTextField="Title" 
                    DataValueField="Value" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="Small" Height="306px" 
                    Width="230px"></asp:ListBox>
            </td>
            <td align="right" dir="rtl" width="30">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="25">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="btnAddResource1" 
                                Text="&gt;" Width="28px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnAddAll" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="btnAddAllResource1" 
                                Text="&gt;&gt;" Width="28px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnRemove" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="btnRemoveResource1" 
                                Text="&lt;" Width="28px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnRemoveAll" runat="server" 
                                meta:resourcekey="btnRemoveAllResource1" Text="&lt;&lt;" Width="28px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td align="left" valign="top" width="250">
                <asp:ListBox ID="lst1" runat="server" DataTextField="Title" 
                    DataValueField="value" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="Small" Height="306px" 
                    Width="230px"></asp:ListBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</ContentTemplate>
```

and here is my behind Code

```
   Public Property UserName As String
    Get
        Return ViewState("UserName")
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        ViewState("UserName") = value

    End Set
End Property
Protected Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    MsgBox(lst2.SelectedItem.Text)
End Sub

Public Sub BindUserNotInGroups()
    Dim objSecurity As New Negso.Security.SecurityHelper()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt = objSecurity.GetNonGroupsForUser(UserName)
    lst2.DataValueField = dt.Columns("SID").ColumnName
    lst2.DataTextField = dt.Columns("Name").ColumnName
    lst2.DataSource = dt
    lst2.DataBind()
End Sub
''' <summary>
''' Binds the user not in groups.
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Sub BindUserInGroups()

    Dim objSecurity As New Negso.Security.SecurityHelper()
    'Dim k = objSecurity.GetGroupsForUser(UserName).Rows.Count
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt = objSecurity.GetGroupsForUser(UserName)
    lst1.DataValueField = dt.Columns("SID").ColumnName
    lst1.DataTextField = dt.Columns("Name").ColumnName
    lst1.DataSource = dt
    lst1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

I Call Binding Functions when Username property will be set :

```
Public Property UserName() As String
    Get
        Return ViewState("UserName")
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)

        ViewState("UserName") = value
        userGroups1.UserName = ViewState("UserName")
        userGroups1.BindUserInGroups()
        userGroups1.BindUserNotInGroups()
        'ListBox3.UserName = ViewState("UserName")
    End Set
```

Comment: When end where do you call `BindUserNotInGroups` and `BindUserInGroups`? You should do that only `If Not Page.IsPostback`.

Comment: i can not use IsPostback . i Call BindUserNotInGroups  and BindUserInGroups when i set UserName Property

Comment: I added some information to my question, please review :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this is not the best way. You should work like this

```
public overrides sub onload()

if (not String.isNullOrEmpty(UserName) and not Page.IsPostBack) OR Me.UserNameChanged then

        userGroups1.UserName = Me.UserName
        userGroups1.BindUserInGroups()
        userGroups1.BindUserNotInGroups()


end if

end sub
```

ok, something like this

```
Public Class testpage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private lst2 As New ListBox
    Private WithEvents btnadd As New Button


    Private _UserNameChanged As Boolean
    Public Property UserNameChanged() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _UserNameChanged
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _UserNameChanged = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property UserName As String
        Get
            Return ViewState("UserName")
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            If ViewState("UserName") <> value Then
                UserNameChanged = True
            End If
            ViewState("UserName") = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If Not Me.Page.IsPostBack And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName) Then
            Me.DataBind(True)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub onbtnClick() Handles btnadd.Click

        If Me.UserNameChanged And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName) Then
            Me.DataBind(True)
        End If

    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub DataBind()

        userGroups1.UserName = Me.UserName
        userGroups1.BindUserInGroups()
        userGroups1.BindUserNotInGroups()

        MyBase.DataBind()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Dear Luke : what do you mean by Me.UserNameChanged ?

Comment: i dont care if protected or not, this is only a fast written example, dude... me.usernamechanged is your custom property which you set in your property "UserName" ... like if viewstate(username) <> value then set usernamechanged = true, but this one you dont save into viewstate, because you need it only once, to bind the stuff

Comment: thanks :) i am novice would you please put some sample code about UserNameChanged ?  and why should i have to override onload ? thanks for help.